# Query MongoDb records from 5 days ago using '_id'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I've read online that '_id' holds a timestamp on when it was created and you are able to query it depending on a date. This is what I've I tried so far, but not having any luck.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);

collection.find( { }, { metal: 1, change: 1, percent: 1, _id: { $gte: d } } ).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Array in Mongo:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "58e21b52524c0b0011fb92f4",
        "metal": "Palladium",
        "change": 3,
        "percent": "+0.38%"
    },
    {
        "_id": "58e21ee3524c0b0011fb92f5",
        "metal": "Gold",
        "change": 6,
        "percent": "+0.54%"
    },
    {
        "_id": "58e21ee3524c0b0011fb92f6",
        "metal": "Silver",
        "change": 0,
        "percent": "+0.77%"
    },
...
```

Much thanks to @robertklep for working through this with me. If anyone else runs into this problem, below is a solution on how to solve it.

Updated Answer:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); //1 would be 1day
var _id = ObjectID.createFromTime(d.getTime() / 1000);

collection.find({ _id : { $gte : _id }}, { metal: 1, change: 1, percent: 1 }).toArray(function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
   ...
});
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `_id` holding the date thing, but I suspect you have to do a `d.getTime()` before running the query

Comment: Have you tried using the `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` method as per the documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `ObjectID` from your timestamp, for which you can use [`ObjectID.createFromTime()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#.createFromTime):

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);

var _id = ObjectID.createFromTime(d.getTime() / 1000); // timestamp should be in seconds
```

After that, you can use `_id` for comparison queries.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep - I am getting this error here however. I just want to get all the records from the last 5days. Error: 'ObjectID is not defined'

Comment: Thanks @robertklep - Almost there. Getting undefined when console logging 'results' however. Should I change anything?  collection.find( { }, { metal: 1, change: 1, percent: 1, _id: { $gte: d } } ).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});

Comment: You should remove the first argument to `find` (the empty object): `collection.find({ metal : 1, ... })`

Comment: Thanks @robertklep - It's returing an empty array now '[ ]'. I updated the question above with what my records in mongo look like

Comment: @user992731 your documents are almost a month old, I assume that you have documents in your database that would match the query you're testing?

Comment: Yes,  there are a ton. I just grabbed the first bit

Comment: Oh hmm, your query still isn't correct, try this: `collection.find({ _id : { $gte : d } }, { metal: 1, change: 1, percent: 1 }).toArray(...)`

Comment: Still empty array. I tried:  var d = new Date();
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);
      var _id = ObjectID.createFromTime(d.getTime() / 1000);

      collection.find({ _id : { $gte : d } }, { metal: 1, change: 1, percent: 1 }).toArray(function(err, results) {
          console.log(results); ...

Comment: `d` in the query should be `_id`, because that's what the variable is called (`collection.find({ _id : _id }, ...)`).

Comment: "collection.find({ _id : { $gte : _id }}," Did the trick. Thanks alot Legend!!